# Why is my font-size percentage not working in CSS?

Tags: css

The h1 font-size percentage isn't changing the text size according to the screen and just stays at 20px. Am I missing something?

```
html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
}
```

Comment: If you're using percentages for font sizes, they inherit the 'baseline' size from their parent elements.  In a webpage with no other elements beside the `H1`, your code produces the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead.

```
font-size:2em;
```

Ems are a more appropriate relative size unit for text. Also, without seeing your html structure, it's hard to know if there isn't some other element obstructing this font-size change.